# iOS navigation bar lighter on some tab pages

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have little problem with navigation bar.

On some tabs it is darker but on some is lighter.

I use same navigation view controller class for both..

```
import UIKit

class NavigationViewController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let backBtnTitle = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backBtnTitle

        navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.12, green:0.6, blue:0.64, alpha:1)
        navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        navigationBar.barStyle = .Black
        let attributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 24)!,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()
        ]
        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

and you can see on this image:
[image]

How can i fix this, to be darker color on both?

Comment: Is it transparent or using any VisualEffect things like blur?

Comment: I don't use visual effects, where can i see if it is transparent?

Comment: Hum I would say by checking the `alpha`
 property

Comment: I fixed it with `self.navigationBar.translucent = false` i think it works now. Thanks.

Comment: Good job! It's offen related to some translusent/alpha stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
self.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

in navigation view controller.

Comment: Holy Molly, I was starting to believe my eyes where going bad.